# Create a Systemwide alias-file in ubuntu

Tags: bash, configuration, alias

I want to have an alias file for every user (even not yet existing). What must be the name of that file in '/etc'?

I know .bashrc is in ubuntu in /etc as bash.bashrc, However there is no skeleton file for aliases. Might be not possible but would be nice.

Comment: Whatever you like. You just need to source it in `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Do you want to support non-`bash` users too?

Comment: Relating, on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/503216/882661. Though I disagree with the advice of modifying `/etc/bash.bashrc` (because it is provided by your distribution), and adding a file in `/etc/profile.d` won't help much with aliases because it is only read by login shells.

Comment: On a related note, `/etc/skel/.bashrc` is copied to new Bash users.

Comment: @Kusalananda: That would be even better ;)